# laravel regex : 00am-00am

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.2 and I need to validate a feild (time_slot).

```
Schema::create('booking', function (Blueprint $table) {
       /// other feilds
        $table->string('time_slot');
       /// other feilds
    });
```

And in Request I have declared rules to validate it.

```
    public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
          //other rules
        'time_slot' => 'required|Regex:/^[0-9am-pm\-]+$/',
    ];
    return $rules;
}
```

I'm looking for a regular expressions that will only accepts values like given below:

```
[digit][digit][am or pm]-[digit][digit][am or pm]
```

example 10pm-11pm.. the combination of two digits must be in the range given below.

```
[00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12]
```

Need help to create this kind of RegeX..
Thank !

Comment: `[]` are character classes they allow single character or ranges. `am-pm` creates a range of `m-p` allowing `m`, `n`, `o`, or `p`, as well as `a` because of the preceding `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping in mind that hours cannot exceed 12.

**Regex:** `^([0][0-9]|[1][012])(am|pm)-([0][0-9]|[1][012])(am|pm)$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO4kO1/3)**

Comment: Could be a bit simpler `[ap]m`, then won't need the capturing.

Comment: Yes it will be but we are not dealing here with 10's of characters to choose from. For two cases I prefer to use alteration. For more than two class will be in handy.

Comment: @noob thanks for your response but i have updated my question.. please check

Answer (score 0):

Check this [regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/gN5gP3/1)

```
$rules = [
    'time_slot' => 'required|Regex:/([0-9]{2})(am|pm)-([0-9]{2})(am|pm)/',
];
```